# Add a new system call in Linux ARM64 system - link error

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, arm64

I am trying to add a new system call to a Debian 11 ARM64 Linux system. Kernel version 5.10.191. The system is running on a UTM virtual machine on Mac M2 laptop.

I am able to compile the kernel, install the new kernel, and boot from the new kernel. I need to add a new system call to the kernel. Here is what I did:

1. Add a new folder, say mycode/ under the root of the source code directory. Add a hello.c, Makefile.
2. In the Makefile of the root directory, I added mycode/ to core-y.
3. Added: asmlinkage long sys_hello(void); to include/linux/syscalls.h
4. Added
   #define __NR_hello 441
   __SYSCALL(__NR_hello, sys_hello)
   to the near end of include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h
5. Make the kernel again.

At the end, I got the error at the final link stage:
ld: arch/arm64/kernel/sys.o:(.rodata+0xdc8): undefined reference to `__arm64_sys_hello'

The above procedure works for X86 architecture. It seems that the architecture of ARM64 has been changed. What did I do wrong in the above process?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you also need to modify the **total number of systemcalls**.

In **include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h**

```
#define __NR_syscalls 442 // 441+1
```

In **arch/arm64/include/asm/unistd.h**

```
#define __NR_compat_syscalls number+1
```